# #1052 - Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1052

```
update callingroute AS t1
INNER JOIN callingroute AS t2                
SET t1.day = (select date FROM (select dayname(date) from callingroute where status = 'OK')AS X) 
WHERE t1.calling_route_id IS NOT NULL;
```

// Any idea why i get these errors

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I doubt this query -- even if fixed -- would do anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anything the query should be shortened to

```
update callingroute AS t1                
SET t1.day = dayname(date) 
WHERE t1.calling_route_id IS NOT NULL
  AND status = 'OK';
```

Comment: WOW Thanks a lot Joakim Danielson. It is working perfectly fine. thanks a millions times